# Derby getGeneratedKey() returning wrong value when inserting one to many relationship

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I have a database that holds a one-to-many relationship between a 'Parent' and 'Child' where the parent can have multiple children. The child table holds the reference to the parent via foreign key constraint. Here are the table queries:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent (
  id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name VARCHAR(55),
  CONSTRAINT pk_parent_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE Child (
  id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name VARCHAR(55),
  parent INT CONSTRAINT fk_parent REFERENCES Parent
  CONSTRAINT pk_child_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

My java code iterates over the parent list where it first inserts the parent into the database so that I can get the **ID** of the parent to use for the association with the child:

```
Statement s = this.conn.getStatement();
s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Parent (name) VALUES ('John')", 
    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet r = s.getGeneratedKeys();
r.next();
int parentId = r.getInt(1);
r.close();
s.close();
```

Now that I have the parent ID, I iterate over the children of that parent (a List in the parent POJO). The code is near identical except for getting the ID of the child and setting its own values. The queries look like this:

```
s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Child (name, parent) VALUES ('Rocky'," + 
    parentId + ")");
```

Running this sequence will work the majority of the time, but eventually, some behavior happens where the ID returned when getting the generated ID from the parent insert query doesn't reference the proper parent ID. This will cause this exception to occur:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: INSERT on table 'CHILD' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'fk_parent_id' for key (97). The statement has been rolled back.
```

I inspected the database after this and noticed that the ID of the violation (97 in this case) doesn't even exist in the parent table. What I don't understand is why or how I am getting an ID back after the single row insert that is not accurate, especially after there have been successful references created before.

Comment: can you change both ids declaration with `id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)`

Comment: @YCF_L this does not make a difference in the behavior I described

Comment: Is the parent row present, but with a different generated ID? If so, what is the different generated ID? Or is the parent row simply not present at all?

Comment: @BryanPendleton the parent row is present. The statement is inserted with no errors and a generated key is returned, and should be of the inserted record per the specification. The returned key in this case however is not to a parent record at all as the record with that id does not exists, but the record that was inserted does exists but with a different Id

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. Derby's support for getGeneratedKeys is a bit buggy, but I haven't heard of this particular bug. What does `this.conn.getStatement()` do, in your code? `getStatement` isn't a method on java.sql.Connection. The value 97 is worryingly close to 100, which I think is a magic "increment size" for the Derby "sequence" object which underlies generated key columns, but, again, I haven't heard of this particular bug before. But try setting derby.language.sequence.preallocator to, say, 500 and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @BryanPendleton changing that property does not change the error behavior. Still getting the same type of exception. The `getStatement() ` is actually `createStatement()`

Comment: @BryanPendleton, could you add that as an answer so I can upgrade it. Derby is found to be a poor production database and better used for development testing.